# Parsing with htmlcleaner

Tags: java, htmlcleaner

I developed a method which allows you to extract items from a specific class using htmlcleaner now I was wondering...

How would you be able to extract the body and all its elements inside an html using htmlcleaner?

```
public String htmlParser(String html){

    TagNode rootNode;
    HtmlCleaner html_cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
    rootNode = html_cleaner.clean(html);
    TagNode[] items = rootNode.getElementsByName("body", true);
    ParseBody(items[0]);
    html = item_found;
    return html;
}

String item_found;
public void ParseBody(TagNode root){
    if(root.getAllElements(true).length > 0){
        for(TagNode node: root.getAllElements(true)){
            ParseBody(node);
        }           
    }else{
        item_found = item_found + root.toString();// root.toString() only brings out the first name inside TagNode
```

> ```
> - In here I wanted just the text of all items in the body but it would still be beneficial for everyone if the question is complete-
> ```

```
        //if(root.getText().toString() != null || !(root.getText().toString().equals("null"))){
            //item_found = item_found + root.getText().toString();
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/javause.php There is an example there on how to traverse the DOM tree.

Comment: @AljoshBre from what I understood it traverse and updates certain items within the DOM tree or is there something I am missing?

Comment: `TagNode[] subnodes = firstNode.getElementsByName("body", true);` Try that and let me know if it works.

Comment: First thing I did before posting this question.

Comment: So I am close to finishing up this question however I am still missing a small variable. To whoever is interested in the code here it is.